# COVID-19 data sets with patient-level demographic information (e.g. age)

Tags: covid-19, data, covid-19-datasets

I'm searching for data sets about Covid-19 patients, where the column "age" occurs for each patient. All the sets I find are summarized, like the one from the [John Hopkins University](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19).

Answer (score 2):

The [UK Biobank](https://news.bugbank.uk/2020/04/interpreting-uk-biobank-covid-19-test.html) (cohort study of 500,000 participants) incorporates SARS-CoV-2 test result data. It contains age, as well as entire medical history information for each participant.

**Ref:** [Dynamic linkage of COVID-19 test results between Public Health England’s Second Generation Surveillance System and UK Biobank](https://doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.12091455) (2020) *

---

<sup>* Disclaimer: I have worked on this project.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16251/covid-19-clinical-data-or-statistics) in opendata.SE has answers that might help.

There are three answers at the time of writing

- [Anthem XPRIZE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/17298/10235)
- [Github large dataset](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/17321/10235)
- [South Korean data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/17366/10235)

Comment: South Korea doesn't seem to actually allow full dataset downloads, based on the answer there.